# Installed Perl but can't install openssl

Tags: javascript, node.js, perl, openssl

So, in this url here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/james-proxy/james/wiki), I need to install HTTPS for this to work however, i do not know how. According to the Docs for Windows, I needed to have Perl installed - in order to install openssl; for which i've succesfully installed Perl done by using this command in a elevated Command Prompt:

```
powershell -Command "& $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/w20598w01/install.ps1'))) -activate-default ActiveState/Perl-5.32"
```

Now that i've installed Perl, it's having me do commands like this to install opensll:

```
  on Windows (only pick one of the targets for configuration):

$ perl Configure { VC-WIN32 | VC-WIN64A | VC-WIN64I | VC-CE }
$ nmake
$ nmake test
$ nmake install
```

for this is where i am stuck at, i've tried running these commands in the same elevated Command Prompt i used to install Perl with, but it does not work! In order for me to enable HTTPS in James Program, i must generate files using OpenSSL! I need help and i'm simply lost!

Comment: "it does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you to run perl on ONE of those targets then use nmake.  eg `perl Configure VC-WIN32` and you need to make sure you do it in the directory with the source and the `Configure` file you are trying to run with perl.

That said, I'm not sure you're doing what you want to be doing - you can install Openssl from binary without having to compile it.  See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: Could you please explain step by step, how and where execute perl confgure command ?